# JPA/Hibernate: EntityManager.close() and IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, bean-managed-transactions

I have a logging service within a JEE environment which uses `TransactionManagementType.BEAN` because the logging should be independent from JTA transactions, so I have to deal with transactions by myself.

Currently this logging service looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class LoggingService
{
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "MyLoggingUnit")
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingService.class.getSimpleName());

    public void log(LogLevel logLevel, String userId, String message)
    {
        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry(userId, message, logLevel);
        try
        {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist(logEntry);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally
        {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

    public LastVisit getLastVisit(String userId)
    {
        LastVisit result = null;
        try
        {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            result = entityManager.find(LastVisit.class, userId);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally
        {
            entityManager.close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void setLastVisit(LastVisit lastVisit)
    {
        try
        {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist(lastVisit);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally
        {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the endpoint which uses this service:

```
@Path("/recipe")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RecipeEndpoint
{
    private RecipeService recipeService;
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @EJB
    public void setRecipeService(RecipeService recipeService)
    {
        this.recipeService = recipeService;
    }

    @EJB
    public void setLoggingService(LoggingService loggingService)
    {
        this.loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addRecipe(RecipeBo recipeBo)
    {
        loggingService.log(LogLevel.OK, recipeBo.getUserId(), "addRecipe: " + recipeBo);

        try
        {
            recipeService.addRecipe(recipeBo);
            loggingService.log(LogLevel.OK, recipeBo.getUserId(), "recipe successfully added: " + recipeBo);
            return Response.ok().entity(new ResponseObject()).build();
        }
        catch (BadRequestException e)
        {
            ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject();
            responseObject.registerException(RecipeService.SAFE_LOCK_TRIGGERED_TEXT);
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(responseObject).build();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            loggingService.log(LogLevel.ERROR, recipeBo.getUserId(), "an error occured while adding a recipe: " + ExceptionToStringMapper.map(e));
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(new ResponseObject(e)).build();
        }
    }
}
```

When I add a recipe, the log method is invoked twice. I can assure that since I have two entries in database, so it works as I need it but when I read the doc of the entityManager.close() method:

> Close an application-managed entity manager. After the close method
>   has been invoked, all methods on the EntityManager instance and any
>   Query and TypedQuery objects obtained from it will throw the
>   IllegalStateException except for getProperties, getTransaction, and
>   isOpen (which will return false). If this method is called when the
>   entity manager is associated with an active transaction, the
>   persistence context remains managed until the transaction completes.
>
> Throws:
>       IllegalStateException - if the entity manager is container-managed

...this actually must not work and throw an `IllegalStateException` since I use the same EntityManager twice. (the first time log is invoked, calls `persist()` and `close()`, then log is invoked again and calls `persist()` and `close()` again). I want to understand why it works and does not throw an exception to not get any bad surprises in future.

Comment: You assume the same stateless-bean instance is used for the second request, but that does not have to be true. Try verifying by printing a hashcode or something like that. See also https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201535

Comment: Thanks, although the topic of the thread is not exactly the same, because he talks about the whole bean. In my case I have one request of the `RecipeEndpoint` which executes `loggingService.log()` twice. Nevertheless, I still don't exactly know why this works, because the `LoggingService` gets injected at the request of `addRecipe()` and then log is invoked twice.But when I print the hash code of the `LoggingService` instance in log method, it's really not the same instance. I'm very confused about that because in my opinion the `LoggingService` instance should live as long as the method runs?

Comment: That's the thing (and somewhat confirmed by the different hashcodes): you do not get an instance of the LoggingService, you get an instance of a proxy to a pool of implementation instances. Each time you invoke a method on the instance, a request goes out to the pool to fetch a "LoggingService implementation instance" and execute the method on the returned implementation instance. In all, a lot happens under water with the annotations you use. You should be able to see some of that when you step through the code in debugging mode.

Comment: Ok, one last question. Can I rely on getting always a new instance, because if I don't, it would cause an exception.

Comment: No, the pool decides that based on how full the pool is, how many concurrent requests there are, validation/time-out of beans in the pool, etc.. To prevent the exception, remove the "PostConstruct" and follow [this idiom](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged).